# Persisting an iframe in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-routing

So I've recently been converting an old project to Angularjs, but there's a bigger section that I can't convert right now, but still need to work inside Angular.

To solve this I used an Iframe. The problem now is when I switch to a different page, the view and by association the iFrame is getting destroyed. This means when I switch back it will reload the iFrame and will lose the user's spot and any data they didn't save on the form. Usually I solve this by storing everything inside a service, but it won't work for this since its an iFrame.

Is there anyway to create the iFrame outside of the context of the template so when I switch back to the page I can call the iFrame to display, rather than reloading it, then I can manually destroy it when I want?

Or is there a better way to go about doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to create an iframe outside the context of a **page** of course, but you could certainly create it outside a view template on your main HTML if by moving back and forth you are using routing to swap views and not reloading the whole page from the server.  If not that then I'll need some more context, like what would keep the data from changing on the old side when the user switched pages?

Comment: You could try and use `ngInclude` for the iFrame instead of loading it in the `ngView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone interested, what I ended up doing is putting the iFrame in a parent template inside an ng-if. When I go to the route I want the iframe in, I set the ng-if to true and leave it as true when I'm selecting different tabs and want it to persist, when I want it to switch or not persist I set the ng-if back to false and everything seems to be working as expected.